# Flutter twitter login without firebase

Tags: android, flutter, authentication, twitter, twitter-login

how to Disable twitter redirection to callback url after sign in
i want to navigate to another screen in my application not to redirect to web page

i tried to add local host url but it ends up "can't be reached"

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution :

- in manifest add this intent filter:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62vdH.png)
red color : YOUR_APP_NAME

- in TwitterLogin Obj set the redirectUrl value with "YOUR_APP_NAME://"
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXTla.png)
- in developer.twitter app settings add the same redirectUrl